# How run programm once in python in linux?

Tags: python

I want to write statement, in which I will check runs that script from other place (on that machine) or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to check for multiple running instances of a program is to use a lock file.  Use your favorite search engine to search for "python lock file" to find various ways to do this, including both convenient packages and various mechanisms in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

```
print "Is anybody runs that script?"
```

If this is not what you want, please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an environment variable as a flag and test if it's on or not.

Comment: probably won't work, as an envvar set by a script won't reach the parent shell.

Comment: what if someone change that environment variable?

Comment: if not that, so a file with owner permissions only that holds the flag